# YouTube embedded video won't show fullscreen button in webview

Tags: android, video, webview, youtube

I am new to Android development and I am trying to make an app for my video website which has videos from YouTube.

The problem I am having right now is that the embedded iframe videos don't show the fullscreen button. I have been searching for a solution but have yet to find one that works for me.

**mainActivity.java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

private WebView wv1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    wv1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    wv1.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    });
    wv1.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    wv1.loadUrl("http://m.youtube.com");

} .....
```

Thanks for any help.